# Acces log for restlet with log4j

Tags: log4j, slf4j, restlet

I am planning to use log4j for restlet web services. I can enable restlet logging with log4j by setting the system property,

-Dorg.restlet.engine.loggerFacadeClass=org.restlet.ext.slf4j.Slf4jLoggerFacade .

But I couldn't find the restlet access log. How can I enable it ?

Thanks,

Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to restlet framework and I followed the steps available in the below link,

http://restlet.org/learn/tutorial/2.1/#part03

I was expecting access log by just adding ServerResource, because I can access the url from the browser. But the access logs generated only after adding application with the help of the below tutorial.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmxVKC5qTVg

Thanks @ZAky for trying to solve my problem.

Ramesh

Answer (score 0):

Do you see /var/logs/jetty? or /usr/share/jetty/logs (on Ubuntu)?
What do you need more then you get there?
Did you try syslog?